# continue persist entity after Exception data too long error in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

How we can store next record in loop when error is Data too long for column 'institute' i write try_catch block in loop and also try continue keyword in catch block then its give me dont flush entity also use entity.flush(), entity.getTransaction().commit() and entity.clear() method

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least no the way you're trying to, if you send all of them in the same transaction you can't avoid error.
Try checking the size with java, if you already know the maxsize of the column.